# Google Sheets API v4 to get all sheet names in a worksheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api

I am using the javascript code as provided in the quickstart section of https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/js

```js
function listMajors() {
       gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
          spreadsheetId: '1b05r8p74UzLh_Hk8119stG8yEoU6Utsr1L238BwssWU',
          range: 'Class Data!A2:E',
        }).then(function(response) {
          var range = response.result;
          if (range.values.length > 0) {
            appendPre('Name, Major:');
            for (i = 0; i < range.values.length; i++) {
              var row = range.values[i];
              // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
              appendPre(row[0] + ', ' + row[4]);
            }
          } else {
            appendPre('No data found.');
          }
        }, function(response) {
          appendPre('Error: ' + response.result.error.message);
        });
      }
```

gives me data in the specified range: Class Data!A2:E.

I now want to list all the sheets (like the one: Class Data) available in a spreadsheet. Please help.

Answer (score 10):

I found it. This should work. I am using C# though. The javascript should be almost the same. 
For more info: [spreadsheet get method information.](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get%22spreadsheet%20get%20method%20information%22)

```
var ssRequest = service.Spreadsheets.Get(sheetId);
Spreadsheet ss = ssRequest.Execute();
List<string> sheetList = new List<string>();

foreach(Sheet sheet in ss.Sheets)
{
    sheetList.Add(sheet.Properties.Title);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
    gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.get({
        spreadsheetId: SPREADSHEET_ID
    }).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.result.sheets)
    }, function(response) {
        console.log('Error: ' + response.result.error.message);
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/15064938)

Comment: Thanks, this is now `response.data.sheets` at least for me following their Node getting started guide with latest packages

Comment: Note that `gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.get` returns *all* data related to the spreadsheet. This is technically correct, but it could be a very heavy call depending on the size of the spreadsheet.